# nested replies to a comment using recursion php

Tags: php, codeigniter, recursion

I have a comment and reply system in which I want to nest replies in an indented manner using recursion. I am getting all the comments and their replies in a normal manner without indentation and everything displayed in an order according to id.

I have a column in the comment table `type` which tells whether it is a comment or reply and another column which stores parentId of the reply.

I have tried something like

```
<?php displayComments($comment); 
         function displayComments($comment) {
                foreach($comment as $value) { ?>
                        <ul class="commentList">
                            <li>
                                <div class="commentData" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
                                    <p><a href="javascript: void(0)"><?php echo $value['author']; ?></a><span class="date"><?php echo $value['date']; ?></span></p>
                                    <p><?php echo $value['content']; ?></p>
                                    <p><span class="reply">Reply</span> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="1"></i> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="1"></i> </p>
                                </div>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
            <?php   }
                } ?>
```

where $comment is an array which stores all the comment and replies.

Please help me how can i display the replies in a nested manner if I know which is a reply and the parentId of the reply

Comment: What is the definition of you $comment array?

Comment: it contains indexes as 0,1,2,3,..... and that index contains values like id, author, date, content, type, parentId etc